# Unnable to use multiple JTA EntityManager at the same time

Tags: java, database, jpa, wildfly, jta

Trying to query data from legacy database (with different datasource) to current database, but got two exceptions in two scenarios.

I've got an implementation like this:

```
class A {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EPU")
  EntityManager schemaEntityManager;

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ELegacyPU")
  EntityManager oldSchemaEntityManager;

  void init() {
     queryFromDatabase();
     // check if it is empty, if true then query from legacy
     queryFromLegacyDatabase();
     recreateLegacyInCurrentDatabase();
  }

  List<E> queryFromDatabase() {
    // query from schemaEntityManager
  }
  
  List<ELegacy> queryFromOldDatabase() {
    // query from oldSchemaEntityManager
  }

  void recreateLegacyInCurrentDatabase() {
    // records -> schemaEntityManager.merge()
  }
}
```

While I'm trying to run this with `@Translational` over `recreateLegacyInCurrentDatabase` method, then got exception from this method (cannot found any valid info over hibernate's TRACE log-level):

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:880)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.merge(AbstractEntityManager.java:567)
```

While I'm trying to run this with `@Translational` over only class **or** over only `queryFromDatabase`/`queryFromOldDatabase` method **or** over any of this two cases + `recreateLegacyInCurrentDatabase`, then got exception from `queryFromOldDatabase` (cannot found any valid info over hibernate's TRACE log-level):

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1575)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
```

I use JTA configured under `persistence.xml` & trying not to use RESOURCE_LOCAL instead of this or there is no option to do this without RESOURCE_LOCAL configuration in `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Is your A class and EJB or CDI bean? In that case, annotating it with Transactional (or the externally *called* methods) with Transactional would do the trick. Please note that internal callings (such as from init() to other Transactional annotated methods) won't be intercepted and, as such, won't start transactions. Can you please show all the annotations and your persistence.xml. It should work with JTA without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just used something like this (also for old PU):

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(getPUName());
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

and in `persistence.xml` we need to change standard `JTA` to `RESOURCE_LOCAL` and `jta-data-source` property to `non-jta-data-source` property:

```
<persistence-unit name="YourPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/YourDS</non-jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

So while using `RESOURCE_LOCAL` we need to secure two things, **transaction**:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
// code
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

and after all remember to **close** things up:

```
entityManagerFactory.close();
```